# TypeError: e._panGestureHandler.current.setNativeProps is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, expo

I have the following `Snack Expo`:

https://snack.expo.io/rJ4mAxhmV

Then, I tried to update the version of `react-navigation` to `3.0.9` and here is the result:

https://snack.expo.io/rkPpag2mV

Here are the only changes I applied to the initial project:

[image]

Text mode below:

```
diff --git a/App.js b/App.js
index 7f4eaf7..09ff71d 100644
--- a/App.js
+++ b/App.js
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ import {
   type Theme,
 } from 'react-native-paper';
 import createReactContext from 'create-react-context';
-import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
+import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
 import RootNavigator from './src/RootNavigator';
 import DrawerItems from './DrawerItems';

@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@ type State = {

 const PreferencesContext: any = createReactContext();

-const App = createDrawerNavigator(
+const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
   { Home: { screen: RootNavigator } },
   {
     contentComponent: () => (
@@ -42,6 +42,8 @@ const App = createDrawerNavigator(
   }
 );

+const App = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
+
 export default class PaperExample extends React.Component<{}, State> {
   state = {
     theme: DefaultTheme,
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 4e6d18a..eb2aec0 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -14,6 +14,6 @@
     "prop-types": "^15.0.0",
     "react-lifecycles-compat": "^3.0.4",
     "react-native-paper": "2.4.0",
-    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
+    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
   }
 }
\ No newline at end of file
```

My problem is that when clicking on whatever entry on the list I get the error:

```
Device: (3:209750) TypeError: TypeError: e._panGestureHandler.current.setNativeProps is not a function. (In 'e._panGestureHandler.current.setNativeProps({hitSlop:s,activeOffsetX:u*o})', 'e._panGestureHandler.current.setNativeProps' is undefined)
```

As you can see here:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

If possible, please, provide back the link with the `Snack Expo` fixed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^3.0.9 is matching to 3.1.0, which depends on a newer version of react-native-gesture-handler only available in SDK32 or greater. I would suggest either changing the version from "^3.0.9" to "3.0.9" or changing to SDK32.

Here's a working Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/react-native-paper